# What step should be considered for CPU/memory shortage in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-administration, perfmon

We recently faced an issue in a server where 12000 concurrent users were trying to access an application but only 120 SQL Server connections were available.

Basic issue I've found is in the architecture of deployment of application and database as below:

- DB & App on Same Server
- Data and log files of all database whether system or user, are on system drive i.e. C:\

**Questions:**

1. By looking what metrics in `perfmon` or taking what steps can I prove the above points as the basic cause?
2. Other than the two causes mentioned above, how to correlate metrics/stats in `perfmon` with a particular SQL Server query?

Comment: These things are already covered in Books Online and various blogs by guys like Brent Ozar, Aaron Bertrand etc. Storing everything in C: though is one of the worst things possible - did no-one think that the data should be stored *somewhere*, at the very least a RAID array?

Comment: There are also courses that cover configuration, storeage, etc. Check Pluralsight's cources, you can access them for free through Microsoft's Dev Essentials program (also free)

Comment: What exactly is the nature application?  Is it web/pc application/phone app etc?  How does it handle connections, does it only connect to DB when it needs data?  What is it written in?

Comment: it's a web application , that collect the campaigning data

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, really appreaciate if you can suggest course on pluralsight.

Comment: @HarsimranjeetSingh Pluralsight:- SQL Server 2008 Administration (70-432): Part 1 by Mel Haynes. Most of the first parts of the course will be useful but "Creating SQL Server 2008 Database" in particular. There is an equivalent course for 2012 as well.